# Laravel hasMany association with multiple columns

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two models

```
model_1
model_2
```

`model_1` has many `model_2`

Now I want to association model_1 hasMany model_2 match with multiple column.

Let me give an example in raw query

```
select ...... from model_1 left join model_2 ON (model_1.f1 = model_2.f1 AND model_1.f2 = model_2.f2)
```

How can I do this in `hasMany` association

Answer (score 4):

I faced this situation while dealing with a pre existing schema. I came up with [this solution](https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships)

After installing [Compoships](https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships) and configuring it in your models *model_1* and *model_2*, you can define your relationships matching multiple columns.

In model_1:

```
public function model_2()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(model_2::class, ['f1', 'f2'], ['f1', 'f2']);
    }
```

In model_2:

```
public function model_1()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(model_1::class, ['f1', 'f2'], ['f1', 'f2']);
    }
```

Compoships supports eager loading.

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work by adding an additional parameter to join on in the model:

```
public function my_joined_columns($mySecondJoinColumnValue)
    {
        return $this->hasMany('NamespaceToOtherModel', 'myIdColumn')
           ->where('my_second_join_column', $mySecondJoinColumnValue);
    }
```

And then I make sure I pass in the parameter:

```
MyModel1::find(1)->my_joined_columns(2)->get()
```