# Multiple foreign keys referencing to one primary key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've been struggling with this for a couple of weeks and I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

I am trying to reference three foreign keys into one primary key on another table.

Here are some information:

**User Table**

```
|---------------------|
|        id           |
|---------------------|
|         1           |
|---------------------|
|         2           |
|---------------------|
|         3           |
|---------------------|
```

**Service Table**

Service table with three foreign keys referencing to user_id

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        id           |     tenant       |  service_person  |     landlord     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         1           |        1         |         2        |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

**User Model**

```
    public function service(){
        return $this->hasMany(Service::class, 'id');
    }
```

**Service Model**

```
    public function tenant(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'tenant');
    }

    public function service_person(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'service_person');
    }

    public function landlord(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'landlord');
    }
```

So when I try to query with `User::find()->service` with tinker, only one of my three users find results, which is the service_person. The other ones just return an empty object.

**Query result:**

```
>>> User::find(1)->service
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3125
     all: [
       App\Service {#3156
         id: 1,
         tenant: 2,
         service_person: 1,
         landlord: 3
       },
     ],
   }
>>> User::find(2)->service
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3165
     all: [],
   }
>>> User::find(3)->service
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3166
     all: [],
   }
```

What I am trying to achieve is looking for all the services related to that user, doesn't matter if that user is the tenant, service_guy or landlord, so I can show it on the front end.

Any idea on how can I achieve that?

Ideally I do not want to do a many to many relationship and create a pivot table.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You could do the following Service::where('service_person', $userID) then you get all the services that are related to that service person.

Comment: In your service relation, you have to specify one of the foreign key columns from the services table. That is why it's working only for the first user as both ids are 1

Comment: Thank you for you reply @Collin. I thought about where(), but my main issue is getting all the services related to the use authenticated, sorta like `auth()-user()->service`, to show on a table

Comment: This can be done right? Service::where('service_person', auth()->user()->id)

Comment: True, but what if the service_person is a landlord and a tenant. What I am trying to achieve is looking for all the services related to that user, doesn't matter if that user is the tenant, service_guy or landlord

Comment: @LucasGuariglia I think this is the same issue. Look at the second answer. He mentions a package that allows specifying multiple columns in a relation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32471084/laravel-hasmany-association-with-multiple-columns

Comment: I've seen that package. It doesn't solve my problem. There is an issue opened 2 days ago with the same question. Thanks though :)

Comment: We need to see the user relations, as they are the one you use in tinker, but only include service model?

Comment: Can you explain why you dont want to use a many to many relation? It would solve your problem quite easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think the problem is for the User model 's relations:

User Model:

```
public function servicesTenants(){
return $this->hasMany(Service::class, 'tenant');
}
public function servicesPerson(){
return $this->hasMany(Service::class, 'service_person');
}
public function servicesLandlord(){
return $this->hasMany(Service::class, 'landlord');
}
```

now, you can try:

```
$user=User::with(['servicesLandlord','servicesPerson','servicesTenants'])->find($user_id);
```

if you want to get all user 's services regardless of the relation you can try:

```
$userServices=Service::where('tenant',$user_id)->orWhere('service_person',$user_id)->
orWhere('landlord',$user_id)->get();
```

Comment: worked great my friend, thanks a mill. Saved my life